# Executing VBS Via QProcess Never Emits readyStandardOutPut

Tags: c++, qt, vbscript, stdout, qprocess

I am unable to get QProcess to read any output from my VBScript.  The script executes both on its own and when called from QProcess, and outputs to QCreator's Application Output, so I know my VBS is executing.  To troubleshoot I've cut my VBS down to:

```
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("Hi")
```

Qt-side I've tried:

- Connecting QProcess's finished, readyReadStandardOutput,
  readyReadStandardError signals
- I have also tried setProcessChannelMode to QProcess::MergedChannels

In the MainWindow constructor:

```
connect(Process,SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()),this,SLOT(processDone()));
```

Slots:

```
void MainWindow::processDone()
{
qDebug()<<"Out";
/*QString str;
str.append(Process->readAllStandardOutput());
qDebug()<<str;*/
}


void MainWindow::runProcess()
{
    QString script = "cscript";
    QStringList args;
    args<<QString(QDir::currentPath()+ "/myVBs.vbs")<<"//NoLogo";
    Process->execute(script,args);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QProcess::execute` is a static method, so `Process->execute(script, args)` is equivalent to `QProcess::execute(script, args)`, i.e. your instance `Process` isn't used at all. Use

```
Process->start( script, args );
```